# AngularJS expression is not able to evaluate string containing hyphen(For IE only, Version - 11)

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

In the example below, if the name contains hyphen('-'), AngularJS expression is not able to evaluate that. Resulting as the value field evaluated to '610' instead of '0610-FC2'.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        '0610-FC2'
        ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl" >
  <li ng-repeat="n in names" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Please try executing the code snippet in IE and check the Value field of list item in Developers' Mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks ok to me in the code snippet here

Comment: It also works well on my side (using IE 11.523.17134.0), please check your IE browser version. Please check your code, whether it contains other code to split the value. You could also test the code snippet on another computer.